# Get document id firestore angular

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I tried to create a auto document id in firestore and get the document id in angular 8 using the following code but I am getting the document Id after the completion of the execution.Can anyone help me?Thanks in advance

```
        this.db.collection("testdata2").add({
        "name": "Tokyo",
        "country": "Japan",
        "Date": this.date
        })
        .then(function(docRef){ 

          component.docid=docRef.id;
          console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id); 

        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
        });
        console.log(component.docid);
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  What's wrong with what you've written so far?

Comment: @DougStevenson 
The value **component.docid** is not getting any value updated, Until I exit the function, but  want it to be done within the function so I can Save the doc id in a array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're using promises which means the callbacks in `then` and `catch` will be called after everything else - in this case they will actually be called after the final `console.log(component.docid)`. If you can specify your method as `async` (See [MDN on async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)) then it should make it easier to reason about it. Rewriting your code would then look like this:

```
try {
    const docRef = await this.db.collection("testdata2").add({
        "name": "Tokyo",
        "country": "Japan",
        "Date": this.date
    });

    component.docid = docRef.id;
    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id); 
} catch (error) {
    console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
}
console.log(component.docid);
```

Comment: Thank you very much @pmccloghrylaing resolved my error an works like a gem